# Why is the elif statement not working? [Python]

Tags: python, if-statement

I want the code to calculate the volume of the body that is choosen by a number between 1 and 5. So for example if u run the code and press 3 it should calculate the volume of a dice.

The problem is that I get the else condition everytime, no matter which number I input. When I see elif examples they only have an print function in them, am I using the if-elif wrong?

I tried changing the input typ, changing operators and tried moving things around but I don't know what is wrong.

````
x = print(int(input("Which body do u want to calculate?:\n [1] Sphere \n [2] Cylinder \n [3] Dice \n [4] Quadar \n [5] Pyramid \n ")))

if x == 1:
    r = int(input("Give the radius in (cm): "))
    sphere_volume = (4/3) * pi * r ** 3
    print("The volume of your body is: " + str(sphere_volume) + " cm^3")
elif x == 2:
    r = int(input("Give the radius in (cm): "))
    h = int(input("Give the height in (cm): "))
    cylinder_volume    = pi * sqrt(r) * h
    print("The volume of your body is: " + str(cylinder_volume) + " cm^3")
elif x == 3:
    k = float(input("Give the edge lenght in (cm): "))
    dice_volume = k ** 3
    print("The volume of your body is: " + str(dice_volume) + " cm^3")
elif x == 4:
    k = float(input("Give the edge lenght in (cm): "))
    a = float(input("Give the depth in (cm): "))
    h = float(input("Give the height in (cm): "))
    quadar_volume = k * a * h
    print("The volume of your body is: " + str(quadar_volume) + " cm^3")
elif x == 5:
    k = float(input("Give the edge length in (cm): "))
    h = float(input("Give the height in (cm): "))
    pyramid_volume = 1/3 * sqrt(k) * h
    print("The volume of your body is: " + str(pyramid_volume) + " cm^3")
else:
    print("Wrong entry. Choose a number between 1 and 5")```
````

Comment: `x = print(...` : the variable will be equal to None, all the time

Comment: What do you understand `print` to return?

Comment: Sry this question was pretty unnecessary as soon as I read the comment by Demi-Lune I saw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = print(int(input("Which body do u want to calculate?:\n [1] Sphere \n [2] Cylinder \n [3] Dice \n [4] Quadar \n [5] Pyramid \n ")))
```

You are setting `x` to whatever `print()` returns, but that function returns `None`.

```
>>> x = print("test")
test
>>> type(x)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Simply change the line to:

```
x = int(input("Which body do u want to calculate?:\n [1] Sphere \n [2] Cylinder \n [3] Dice \n [4] Quadar \n [5] Pyramid \n "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the first line of the code if u change it to this it works. Thanks to Demi-Lune

```
x = int(input("Welchen Körper möchten Sie berechenn:\n [1] Kugel \n [2] Zylinder \n [3] Würfel \n [4] Quadar \n [5] Pyramide \n "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just refactor to

```
x = int(input("Which body do u want to calculate?:\n [1] Sphere \n [2] Cylinder \n [3] Dice \n [4] Quadar \n [5] Pyramid \n "))
print(x) # 1 or 2 or 3..
```

Because print always return None

```
word = "anything"
p = print(word) # "anything"
print(p) # None
```